# Issue unlink with Drupal 9.0.3

Tags: php, drupal, debian

I'm new here, i have a problem with Drupal 9.0.3 and I'm not that much of a Drupal expert either.
The problem is this: after i do "drush cache-rebuild", this happen

```
[warning] unlink(/bitnami/drupal/sites/default/files/css/css_GBUUzqz5ceINiDlSQ1o7Z8ZvirKTZAlcfXIJ2cvHW6Q.css.gz): Permission denied FileSystem.php:124In FileSystem.php line 324:                                                                               Failed to unlink file 'public://css/css_GBUUzqz5ceINiDlSQ1o7Z8ZvirKTZAlcf    XIJ2cvHW6Q.css.gz'.
```

I also tried to play a bit with the permissions but nothing happens. I honestly don't know which module or modification of the last ones will have led to this sudden error. Thank you for all kinds of support.

Comment: If you are using nginx , try to `chown -R www-data:www-data /bitnami/drupal/sites/default/files` also you can learn about permissions : https://www.drupal.org/node/244924

Answer (score 1):

You got that warning because the user you are logged in does not have `write` permission on the folder `/bitnami/drupal/sites/default/files/css/`. So, drush (running as that user) cannot delete the aggregated css files while rebuilding the cache.

To solve this, you need to set the permissions of that folder to 775 and make sure that the user you are logged in with belongs to the `group-owner` of it.

Answer (score -1):

I solved with `sudo drush cache-rebuild`

However, thanks equally to both you guys.